# How i can recognize big tap on the iPhone back?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiaccelerometer

I want to recognize a big tap on the iPhone back using accelerometer? How i can do this?

Thanks the answers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html).

Comment: thanks, but i need a more specific thing example an equation.

Comment: Why not try playing around with Apple's sample code that provides a nice real-time graph of the 3 accelerometer axes. Tap on the back and see how each axis responds depending on the current orientation of the device. It should give you at least a starting point for some kind of equation.

Comment: I try to calculate a value, which filters the taps, but on other device the value is change. Example: on iPad 2 filter.z > 1.3 then the user tap the phone, but in ipod Touch 3 the correct value is 2.5 ....